# C# Identify class based on string variable

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm am a very new to c# and been watching and doing some tutorials. I managed to build a simple console guessing game. However now I want to go a little bit beyond the tutorial but I run in to issues and don't seem to get the answer from google or youtube unfortunately...

So I have created a new class called SecretWord and populated this with "secret1" and "secret2" with a word and a few clues.

Then I put this in to array and randomize a number based of the entries in the class to return either "secret1" or "secret2" I then want to populate my hint method with the respective secret{X}.hint1 value but when I try to select it and just console write it I get an error.

So the question is, how do I call my class with the secretClass variable containing the class name?

Thank you in advance and helping me learn! :)

```
 SecretWord secret1 = new SecretWord("Ape", "It's an animal.", "It climbs trees.", "Planet of the ...", "Looks like human.");
        SecretWord secret2 = new SecretWord("Dog", "It has four legs", "It barks", "Man's best friend", "Woof woof");

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randSecretKey = rnd.Next(1, SecretWord.secretCount);

        string secretClass = "secret" + randSecretKey;

        Console.WriteLine(secretClass.hint1);
```

Comment: There's no array of secrets, you have two distinct variables instead of an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly. You variables like `secret1` and `secret2`. And you are generating `string` variable which value can be equal to the variable names, and you want to access these variables now, right ?

You can do some work around to solve this issue.

You can define properties in this class with name `secret1` of type  `SecretWord`. And with use of reflection you can access them by name. Example is below.

```
this.GetType().GetField("secret1").GetValue(
```

You can also use `GetProperty` method.